# How to select many to one to many without hundreds of queries using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-optimization, django-orm

My database has the following schema:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pass

class Tag(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    attr1 = models.CharField()
    attr2 = models.CharField()
    attr3 = models.CharField()

class AlternatePartNumber(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

In other words, a `Product` has many `Tag`s, and a `Product` has many `AlternatePartNumber`s.  `Tag`s are a collection of attributes of the `Product`.

Given the three attributes in a `Tag`, I want to select the associated `Product`s that match (could be more than one), as well as all of the `AlternatePartNumber`s of each product.

Currently I do this:

```
# views.py
results = Tag.objects.
    filter(attr1=attr1).
    filter(attr2=attr2).
    filter(attr3=attr3)

# a template
{% for result in results %}
    {% for alternate in result.product.alternatepartnumber_set.all %}
        {{ alternate.property }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This can run thousands of queries, depending on the number of matches.  Is there a good way to optimize this?  I tried using `Tag.objects.select_related().filter...` and that helped some, but it didn't help enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relationship between Product and AlternatePartNumber is a reverse ForeignKey relationship, so `select_related()` won't work.  You need `prefetch_related()`, which is a little less aggressive than `select_related()` but can handle many-to-one relationships.

I haven't used prefetch_related() myself before but if I'm reading [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) correctly, you need something like `Tag.objects.prefetch_related('product__alternatepartnumber_set').filter...`.  If that doesn't work, specify a related_name on the AlternatePartNumber model and use that instead of `alternatepartnumber_set`.

Comment: I had to add the related_name, but using prefetch_related dramatically reduced the number of queries.  Thanks much!