# Django Query prefetch_related: 'exceptions.NameError' object does not support item assignment

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have one to many relationship table. this is my model

```
class Pointofsale(models.Model):
   official_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False,null=False)
   transaction_number = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
   company = models.ForeignKey("User_company")
   customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer")

class Pointofsale_details(models.Model):
   pointofsale = models.ForeignKey(Pointofsale, related_name='pointofsale_details')
   item = models.ForeignKey("Inventory")
   quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 19, decimal_places = 6, default = 0.0)
```

I want to get the sales with the items in this format

> { official_receipt :100,..,etc, pointofsale_details : [ {item1} , {item2} ] }

OR ( for summary reporting purposes )

> [{ official_receipt :100,..,etc, pointofsale_details : [ {item1} , {item2} ] },{ official_receipt :100,..,etc, pointofsale_details : [ {item1} , {item2} ] }]

I tried this query for a single query but to no avail:

```
transaction_details = Pointofsale.objects.filter(company=get_current_company(request)).prefetch_related('pointofsale_details')
```

I get this error

> 'exceptions.NameError' object does not support item assignment

Is this is correct or proper way to handle one to many relationships?
What am I missing?

If this is unclear please feel free to comment below, so i could refine my question. Thank you!

Cheers!

```
def get_current_company(request,company_obj = False):
    company = request.session.get('company_id',None)
    return company
```

References:

- [Django query in One to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721957/django-query-in-one-to-many-relationship)
- [How to select many to one to many without hundreds of queries using Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322017/how-to-select-many-to-one-to-many-without-hundreds-of-queries-using-django-orm)
- [Django ORM: Selecting related set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853184/django-orm-selecting-related-set)

Comment: Please show us the full traceback and how does the function `get_current_company()` look like.

Comment: Hi, i've added the code you requested